# trying to do multiple inserts in one trigger using field dependent on first insert

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to manipulate a bunch of table triggers that start with an insert into one event table (TB A). This insert fires a trigger (T1) that does an insert into a secondary table (TB B). The secondary table has an insert trigger (T2) that does an update on the first table (TB A).

Pardon the confusion but basically I wanted to ensure that for the first trigger, do a second insert in the same table using the values of the first insert.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @Time int
declare @DeleteLinger int

select @Time = convert(integer,value) from Systemproperty 
   where [name] = 'KeepStoreLingerTimeInMinutes'
select @DeleteLinger = convert(integer,value) from Systemproperty 
   where [name] = 'KeepDeleteLingerTimeInMinutes'
IF (@DeleteLinger >= @Time) SET @Time=@DeleteLinger+1

insert StorageQueue 
    (TimeToExecute,Operation,Parameter,RuleID,GFlags)
  select  DateAdd(mi,@Time,getutcdate()), 1,  I.ID, r.ID, r.GFlags
         from inserted I, StorageRule r
         where r.Active=1 and I.Active=0 and (I.OnlineCount > 0 OR 
     I.OnlineScreenCount > 0)

 -- try and get the value that was just inserted into StorageQueue

select  @SFlags=S.GFlags FROM StorageQueue S, StorageRule r, inserted I 
    WHERE r.ID = S.RuleID and I.ID = S.parameter
 -- if a certain value do another insert into StorageQueue
If (@SFlags = 10)
    INSERT INTO StorageQueue 
        (TimeToExecute,Operation,Parameter,RuleID,StoreFlags)
   VALUES(DateAdd(mi,@Time,getutcdate()), 1, (SELECT parameter 
    FROM StorageQueue),2, @SFlags)
END
```

The problem is that there seems to be either an issue that the record is not yet inserted because the variable @SFlags is null or some other trigger accesses the values and makes changes. My question is whether this is a good way to do it. Is it possible to retrieve a value into the variable from within a trigger because it seems whichever way I try it, it doesnt work.

Comment: Time to start over. Start by using best practices and modern coding techniques. That means joining using the join clause. Next post a usable script. Assign a scalar variable using SET, not SELECT. You posted part of ONE trigger, yet you refer to multiple tables (and triggers). We also can't see the table for which the above trigger snippet was created. The logic you did post makes assumptions which are not always valid (e.g., the insert to storagequeue actually inserts 1 and only 1 row).

Comment: Lastly there does not appear to be a real relationship between inserted and StorageRule - are you assuming something here in that join?

Comment: thanks for response. I actually found the issue and then opted for a different approach. Will submit my answer or just close this question. Thanks again and took you advise on coding techniques.